# lcov and gcovr -r commands are generating the cpp file code coverage report for UT

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

`lcov` and `gcovr -r .` not generating the code coverage report for ***.cpp** files.

I am new to googletest framework. I have written a UT to test the code functionality and compiled the code with options `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage` and `lgcov` in Makefiles. After executing the test-cases, I am able to see the ***.gcno** and **.gcda** files. But not getting the proper code coverage report.

Step 1:  update the Makefile --> `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage`
Step 2:  build the code.
Step 3:  running the test cases.
Step 4:  `gcovr -r .`

Observed:  Not getting ***.cpp** file coverage for which test cases are execute.

Answer (score 1):

I had some troubles getting my test coverage set up, but I finally got it working.  Although I'm not use the tools you are using.

I'm using clang++ and the LLVM tools. And I'm using my own barebones unit testing framework, which is similar to Catch2 (but not nearly as fully featured as Catch2).

Here are the commands I run, in case this is of help to you:

```
clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-c99-compat -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,null -std=c++17 -O0 -g -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping Experiment.cpp

./a.out --test-noisy --test-only

llvm-profdata merge -sparse default.profraw -o default.profdata

llvm-cov show -format=html -tab-size=4 ./a.out -instr-profile=default.profdata Experiment.cpp > default.html

echo '<style>pre { font-family: Monaco, Consolas, monospace; }</style>' >> default.html
```

I'd like to have responded in a comment, but this response is too long and needed the formatting for legibility.  If deemed inappropriate (via downvotes) I'll delete it.